# Changed .htaccess now can't POST back?

Tags: php, xampp

So yeah I changed my .htaccess to get rid of the file extensions in my url. And now I've noticed that I can't post back anything like forms or anything like that?

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/Main/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/Main/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I'm using `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` in my form and I think that might have to be changed to reflect the .htaccess? I'm really at a loss here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's your `.htaccess` file problem.

If you remove `.php` extension from file, your form action attribute needs to reflect this change.

You can do this by simply passing `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` variable to to [trim()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pl/function.trim.php) function, like so:

```
<form action="<?php echo trim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') ?>" method="POST">
    <input name="example" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now your form should submit properly.

Comment: That was it! Thank you.